# How to query all values of a nested field with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, database, elasticsearch

I would like to query a value in all data packages I have in Elasticsearch.

For example, I have the code :

```
  "website" : "google",
  "color" : [
    {
      "color1" : "red",
      "color2" :  "blue"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have this code for an undefined number of website. I want to extract all the "color1" for all the websites I have. How can I do ? I tried with match_all and "size" : 0 but it didn't work.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to query nested object you would need to map them as a nested field first then you can query nested field like this:

```
GET //my-index-000001/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "color"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "test2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "color.color1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your result should look like this for the query:

```
"aggregations": {
    "test": {
        "doc_count": 5,
        "test2": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "red",
                    "doc_count": 4
                },
                {
                    "key": "gray",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

if you check the aggregation result back you will have list of your `color1` with number of time it appeared in your documents.

For more information you can check Elasticsearch official documentation about Nested Field [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and Nested aggregation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).